# Counting differences in 2 strings which have the same length

Tags: java, string, comparison

Let's say I have two strings with the same character length. They look something like this.

```
String s1 = "R20k20r20";
String s2 = "R21k20r20";
```

I don't really care about **where** the differences are, but I want to be able to count how many differences they have between them. In this case, it should be just 1. What would be the easiest way to accomplish this given the circumstances?

Comment: Use loop to iterate over corresponding characters, compare them, if they are not the same increase counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate up to the length of the strings and increment a counter for each different character:

```java
int numDiffs = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); ++i) {
    if (s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i)) {
        ++numDiffs;
    }
}
```

Or you could stream this length for an arguably more elegant one-liner:

```java
long numDiffs = 
    IntStream.range(0, s1.length()).filter(i -> s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i)).count();
```